# R kmeans results not varying with parameter changes

Tags: r, k-means

I'm trying to learn to use the kmeans function in R, using the supplied "iris" data set.

```
data(iris)
mx<-data.matrix(iris)
kx<-kmeans(mx[,-5],centers=3, iter.max=3, nstart=3)
kx$tot.withinss
```

My understanding is it is meant to randomly select different *centers* each time it is run, perform *iter.max* iterations, and repeat *nstart* times to select the option with the lowest *tot.withinss*.

No matter how I change *iter.max* or *nstart*, or even try to specify various *centers* myself, I get the same solution (with *tot.withinss=78.85144*).

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong, or what I am not comprehending properly?

Comment: Please check `withinss` vs. `tot.withinss` in  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html and check them in diffeent runs (with same `centers`): this should be enough to move forward

Comment: I used that as a reference already but checked again; I think I understand and am using them properly.  Still get the same value for tot.withinss every time; ditto (as you would expect) withinss is also the same, the only difference is the id numbers for each cluster can vary between runs.  I do get error messages with less than 3 iterations, and a different (worse) results for nstarts=1. But iter.max=3 and nstarts=2 is enough to arrive at the final solution. Does this indicate the algorithm is working perfectly and is just incredibly efficient on this small data set?